# progressive-web-application with webpack.js

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox, webpack-5

In webpack.js version 5 I wanted to use PWA which according to their webpack documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/progressive-web-application/
I was told to use Workbox, but Workbox is only used for Offline mode, for example, if I want to use other features such as Notifications, IndexedDB, etc., what code should I add in webpack.config.js and also how to use manifest.json With webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the precaching behavior described in https://webpack.js.org/guides/progressive-web-application/ *and* you want to customize your service worker, the cleanest approach would be to use the [`InjectManifest`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#injectmanifest_plugin) `workbox-webpack-plugin`, and pass in the path to your custom service worker file as the `swSrc` option.

The `InjectManifest` plugin will take care of bundling your `swSrc` file, and it will replace `self.__WB_MANIFEST` with a precache manifest based on your `webpack` compilation's assets.

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // Your other webpack config goes here.
  plugins: [
    new InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './service-worker.js',
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
      // Any other config if needed.
    }),
  ],
};
```

```js
// service-worker.js

import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';
// Add in additional imports here as needed.

// This line of code ensures that everything in your webpack
// compilation gets precache and served.
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Your custom service worker code goes here.
```